# Javascript variable undefined but alert outputs variable

Tags: javascript, undefined

I keep getting result is undefined but alert outputs result!
A bit puuzzling, the same thing happens in Chrome and IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>  
  </head> 
<body>


<form id="frm1" action="#" method="post">
  Yammer ID: <input type="text" name="y_id"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
</form> 
<p id="demo">uuu</p>

<script> 
function myFunction() {
  frm_i=document.getElementById("frm1");
  result=frm_i.elements[0].value;
  alert (result);
}    
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;    
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I put:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
```

inside the function and i do not get an error, the uuu briefly changes to the input text then just as quickly changes back to uuu. But I get no error message this way.

Comment: Your page is refreshing because you're submitting a form. Either pull the button out of the form or look up how to prevent a form from submitting.

Comment: Where exactly do you get the error? `result` is only defined within `myFunction`. It can't be accessed from outside of it.

Comment: Declare `result` like this `var result = ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `var` to `frm_i` and `result` and place:

> `document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = result`

Inside the function. It was out of scope.

Added a test server to verify success and changed #demo to an `<output>`

In order to prevent the form from refreshing after submitting, you can add the `target` attribute to the `<form>`:

> ```
>  <form id="frm1" action="http://httpbin.org/post" method="post" target='ifm'>
> ```

The value of `target` can be any location you have control over and `'_blank'` which is a new page (just like an anchor). If you prefer that the submit goes nowhere, then use:

> ```
>  target='#/'
> ```

In this Snippet, I submitted to the test server then redirected the response to a blank iframe by using the iframe's name attribute.

**SNIPPET**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>


  <form id="frm1" action="http://httpbin.org/post" method="post" target='ifm'>
    Yammer ID: <input type="text" name="y_id"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
    <output id='demo'></output>
  </form>

  <iframe name='ifm' src='about:blank'></iframe>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var frm_i = document.getElementById("frm1");
      var result = frm_i.elements[0].value;
      alert(result);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks I think my biggest issue was my scoping, thanks for highlighting it.

Comment: Yeah, it's a simple mistake, I added the rest to show you some options, which are useful for testing.  Happy coding.